# Player won't jump in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

no matter what I do with my code, the Player doesn't seem to want to jump. Everything is referenced correctly in Unity and the code is hopefully error free. I've also checked to see if the Input System is corresponding to what I've got pressed. The only thing I can think of is the force isn't strong enough for the player to lift off of the ground, due to the high gravity (7f). But I lowered the gravity and nothing changed. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    private float speed = 8f;
    private float jumpingPower = 16f;
    private bool isFacingRight = true;

    private bool isJumping;

    private float coyoteTime = 0.2f;
    private float coyoteTimeCounter;

    private float jumpBufferTime = 0.2f;
    private float jumpBufferCounter;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;

    private void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (IsGrounded())
        {
            coyoteTimeCounter = coyoteTime;
        }
        else
        {
            coyoteTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jumpBufferCounter = jumpBufferTime;
        }
        else
        {
            jumpBufferCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (coyoteTimeCounter > 0f && jumpBufferCounter > 0f && !isJumping)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);

            jumpBufferCounter = 0f;

            StartCoroutine(JumpCooldown());
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);

            coyoteTimeCounter = 0f;
        }

        Flip();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapBox(groundCheck.position, groundCheck.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size, 0f, groundLayer);
        //return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        if (isFacingRight && horizontal < 0f || !isFacingRight && horizontal > 0f)
        {
            Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
            isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
            localScale.x *= -1f;
            transform.localScale = localScale;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator JumpCooldown()
    {
        isJumping = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.4f);
        isJumping = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works fine and the player jumps and moves without problems

Make sure to perform these steps inside Unity Engine
Inside the player you must add

1. Rigidbody2D
2. Box Collider2D
3. the code
   Inside the code you must specify

- Ground Layer : "Ignore Raycast"
- Ground Check : "The ground the player is walking on"

And inside the ground must be added

- Layer : "Ignore Raycast"
- Component: "Box Collider2D"

As in these pictures

**Player**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvIO6.png)

**Ground**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W6mh.png)

Comment: Thanks for the "Ignore Raycast" tip. Although this does work, it means you can jump infinitely. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are most welcome. If the problem is solved, you can finish the question by choosing the best answer

Comment: All done aha! Much thanks!